# Using Laravel & cashier to check Stripe subscription status directly from stripe

Tags: php, laravel

I can use the following to check the subscription from within the database.
This outputs the data from the database.

```
{{Auth::user()->subscriptions }}
```

But, how do i check if that subscription is still active via Stripe?

If the subscription is cancelled or runs out, how does this database/system know this.

I hope there is something like **ConnectToStripe('CustomerStripeID')** to retrieve the subscription details

p.s - not enough rep to add tags: 5.4, Stripe or Cashier

Comment: Aren't webhooks supposed to update that?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Stripe but according to [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/billing#checking-subscription-status) you can apply `->subscribed('plan_name'`) to check the subscriptions, quick example:

```
   if(Auth::user()->subscribed('plan_name')){
      //he is subscribed!
   }
```

So you have to loop your subcriptions plans to check all:

```
   @foreach(Plans::get() as $plan)
    {{(Auth::user()->subscribed($plan->plan_name)) ? 'Subscribed!' : 'Not Subscribed'}}
   @endforeach
```

Comment: This doesn't check stripe, This only checks the subscriptions table in the database.

I need to check stripes systems to see if the user is subscribed. As per my OP

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the status of the subscriptions. sometimes a subscription was successful in Stripe, but not in my local database. So I had to check it with Stripe and update it manually.

```
$user = Auth::user();
$subscription = $user->subscription('default');
$id = $subscription->latestPayment()->id;
$payment = new Payment(
    StripePaymentIntent::retrieve($id, Cashier::stripeOptions())
);
if($payment->isSucceeded()){
    // update subscription status
}
```